# How does a NSSortDescriptor work internally and what is its complexity..?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nssortdescriptor

As stated above how does a NSSortDescriptor work internally and what is its complexity..?
I could not find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sort descriptor doesn't have complexity. It's not a sort algorithm. It's just a description of what to compare and how — e.g. a given property, using `-localizedStandardCompare:`, ascending.

The sort algorithm is what would have complexity. For example, the implementation of `-[NSMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:]` uses some sort algorithm and that would have complexity. However, the precise sort algorithm of these methods is not documented. That gives Apple the freedom to change them if they can figure out a better algorithm for the most common use cases.